Syntax error in Parameters to function in python
Receiving a syntax error when attempting to call a function from another function. This in Python 3.12.
I am not sure what is wrong with the code:
E       def formatAuthorityNames(authorityName: str):
E                                             ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What is wrong with the code?
This was working prior to updating to Python 3.12 from 3.10.

The actual error may be somewhere above the indicated place.

This sounds like you're not using the Python version you're trying to use. Try import sys; print(sys.version) and see what that says.

I'm guessing you inadvertently downgraded to Python 2, since it's failing on a type annotation.  Note that macOS comes with Python 2, so if in the process of installing the update you modified your PATH and/or symlinks you might have ended up with the system version as the default.  (Check which python to see which Python is in your PATH.)
